# How can I make my materialize text areas not cut off?

Tags: html, textarea, materialize

I am using materialize to make two messages that will be displayed in the form of textareas on cards. I will use javascript DOM manipulation to allow some users to edit them, and make it readonly for some users. I have added all the javascript code, and it works just fine, but the problem is with HTML, not javascript. The textarea only shows one and a half lines and then cuts off.
[image: The text is cut off]

Here is my code:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="card green accent-1">
            <div class="card-content blue-text" id="general-messages-card">
            <span class="card-title">General Messages</span>
            <textarea class="blue-text materialize-textarea" onchange="generalMessagesUpdate()" style="border: none;" id="general-messages"></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to enable auto resize. but it seems like it still has an upper limit

```
M.textareaAutoResize($('#my-textarea'));
```

You can also trigger it to resize by using :

```
$('#my-textarea').trigger('autoresize');
```